# PostgreSQL outputs table formatted as array instead of table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am experimenting with functions in PostgreSQL, and I got it working fine, but there is something confusing. I have this header of the function:

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION p.GetEvents(date) 
        RETURNS TABLE (when date,  participant varchar, helper varchar) 
        AS $$
        BEGIN
            (....)
```

And I thought this was going to return a table (hence the `RETURN TABLE`!) Something like this:

```
when    |    participant    |    helper
--------+-------------------+-----------
        |                   |
```

but instead is returning me the results looking like an array, such as:

```
(2015-03-21, participant, helper)
(2015-04-10, participant, helper)
```

Isn't `RETURNS TABLE` the right way to build a table as output? How can I force that the output is a table and not comma separated values?

Comment: Use `select * from p.getevents(current_date)`.

Comment: whoops... that was it, I was calling the function without the * FROM... If you feel like typing an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
select * from getevent(current_date);
```

because

```
select getevent(current_date);
```

returns rows with one column of pseudotype *record*.